# Using .byte in beq

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, mips

I have a function and I want to check if my paremeter is equal to iOne but how can I compare a register with a .byte?

On the top I have iOne like this:

```
iOne:   .byte   1
```

and inside my function the first command should be something like this:

```
beq   $a0, iOne, exit   #exit if n == 1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Load the value from memory into a register, then compare the register with the parameter.

Comment: to be honest I already thought that but the point is to use iOne

Comment: You are using `iOne` this way.  Perhaps I don't understand your question correctly.  If you want `iOne` to be more like a symbolic constant than a variable in memory, consider defining it with `.equ iOne, 1` instead.  Then you can do `li $0, iOne; beq $a0, $0, exit` or something like that.

Comment: Some assemblers would even let you do `beq $a0, 1, exit`, and thus would probably allow `beq $a0, iOne, exit` if it were a `.equ` constant, as a pseudo-instruction that loads into a temp register.  (But not `$0`, @fuz; MIPS `$0` is the zero register, like AArch64 XZR.  `$t0` would be a reasonable choice.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I don't really do much MIPS.

Comment: @fuz: On many RISCs (including MIPS, RISC-V, PowerPC), register number zero is a zero register all the time, not like AArch64 where context-dependent meaning lets it share a register number with XZR and the stack pointer.  IDK if that general rule of thumb helps remember things, since you'd still have to remember that there might be a zero register somewhere.  Also usually a bad idea to mix reg numbers with "ABI names" like `$a0`, you don't want to accidentally use two different names that are actually the same register.

Comment: @PeterCordes On PPC specifically, you can assign a value to register zero.  However, many instructions are hard-wired to use zero instead of the register's content (not unlike Intel's treatment of the `k0` register).  I used a plain register number as I wasn't able to find the definition of the ABI register names within one minute of searching and decided that this would be good enough for an example.  Seems like it wasn't...

Comment: @fuz: Yeah there's a surprising amount of crud in the google search results for `mips registers`, but luckily due to my browser showing links in a different colour if I've already visited them, I could scroll down to https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node10.html and find a table that didn't suck and wasn't in a PDF.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File is not bad, either.

Comment: you load the value stored in `iOne` to a register and then you compare 2 regsisters...

Answer (score -2):

```
add    $s3, $zero, $zero
```

This performs the addition $s3 = 0 + 0, effectively setting the register $s3 to a value of zero.

```
lb     $t0, 1($s3)
```

This loads a byte from a location in memory into the register $t0. The memory address is given by 1($s3), which means the address $s3+1. This would be the 0+1=1st byte in memory. Since we have a big-endian architecture, we read bytes the 4-byte chunks "big end first".

```
byte:  0   1   2   3
      00  90  12  A0
```

The 0th byte is 00, and the 1st byte is 90. So we load the byte 90 into $t0.

```
sb     $t0, 6($s3)
```

This stores a byte from the register $t0 into a memory address given by 6($s3). Again this means the address $s3+6.

```
byte:  4   5   6   7
      FF  FF  FF  FF
```

becomes

```
byte:  4   5   6   7
      FF  FF  90  FF
```

Now, what if the architecture was little-endian? This would mean bytes are arranged "little end first" in memory, so the effect of the 2nd and 3rd instructions change.

```
lb     $t0, 1($s3)
```

This loads the byte in memory address 1 into register $t0. But now the addresses are "little end first", so we read 12 into the register instead.

```
byte:  3   2   1   0
      00  90  12  A0
```

Next...

```
sb     $t0, 6($s3)
```

This stores the byte in register $t0, which is 12 into a memory address 6. Again with little-endian architecture:

```
byte:  7   6   5   4
      FF  FF  FF  FF
```

becomes

```
byte:  7   6   5   4
      FF  12  FF  FF
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure this answer is for my question?

Comment: @kyriakos0801: It doesn't.  You do want `lb` to load the value into a register to compare against, but this answer doesn't show doing that. It's loading from absolute address `1` in a convoluted way, not your `iOne` label/symbol address.  And most of it is about endianness, but `lb` is a single-byte load so it behaves the same on big or little-endian MIPS.  (Sign-extending the byte into the register, and registers don't have endianness.  Only if you did a word store would the system state then depend on endianness.)